# mod_rewrite RewriteCond problem

Tags: mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file I have the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myblog.com/        
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ blog/author.php?author=$1&contactid=$2 [L]
       RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*[^/index.php])/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ blog/index.php blog=$1&category=$2&article=$3 [L]
```

My problem is that a request like this myblog.com/author/Jim+Jones/28 is getting redirected to the following rule, even though I have a [L] flag there?

How can I exclude the second rule from firing when "/author/" appears in the URL?

Many thanks, Jason

Answer (score 0):

/author/Jim+Jones/28 shouldn't get caught by any of these as neither of your rules catch URLs starting with / and the ^ at the start of you regex-es clearly stats that for the first rule it must start with 'author/' (note no / at the start).

UPDATE:
What I think is happening is that requests like myblog.com/author/Jim+Jones/28 are being rewritten twice. First by the first rule and then by the second one. If that's the case you'll need to make the 2nd rule more restrictive. Don't let it rewrite requests that have author.php in them for example.

UPDATE 2:
OK, so what would probably be the best in your case is to add a condition for the 2nd clause:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myblog.com/        
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ blog/author.php?author=$1&contactid=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(author\.php)
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*[^/index.php])/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ blog/index.php?blog=$1&category=$2&article=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks gligoran, I missed the RewriteBase in my example. I've updated the rules...

Comment: Update:  "If that's the case you'll need to make the 2nd rule more restrictive." That's what I'm trying to do?? How can I do that?

Comment: BTW: You have a small error in your second rewrite rule. The URL it rewrites too is missing the ? between the main part and the query string.

Comment: BTW 2: What are you trying to do with: [^/index.php] in the second rule? A character class like [^chars] means that non of those chars will be matched. What you've done there is that the first group can't end with chars /, i, n, d, e, x, ., p and h. And that's only on character. Regexes are hard and using a tool like Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) can help a lot, because it gives you a tree that explains what's going on.